# Simplifying Use of Script for Non-Technical Users

Tags: python, user-interface

Good day,

I have a script that collects a variety of information from a website and returns it in the console. I then copy individual lines of the information into several different reports. This is fine for me, but a normal user might be confused opening a script for editing, running it, and working in the IDLE console. However, in the interests of continuity, I'm looking for a way to simplify the use of the script for non-technical users.

An important note is my technical limitations. The systems I work on have Python 2.6.5 installed. The script must run from a network drive and be system independent (nothing installed). I cannot install anything on the development testbed.

I would, theoretically, prefer a GUI, because that's what most users are familiar with, however, the popular ones I've looked into require installing plugins, which I can't do.

I've thought about outputting the results to a text file, but I'm unsure how to automatically open the text file for the user to manipulate.

I'm not sure Python is the best solution for this or the complete solution, so I'm looking for ideas that use standard Windows features and do not require any kind of installation or admin privileges.

Deployment systems are Windows XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could output the information to a simple website, using a micro framework like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).

You wouldn't need anything more then the single bottle.py file to use it, and it works on Python 2.6

Comment: Wow, that looks great! I'm not sure it'll work with the firewall, but I'm going to give it a try and hope for the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are worried about users "opening a script for editing, running it, and working in the IDLE console". Why would they need to do this? Probably **to specify the website** to be accessed, right? Modify your script to ask a website from the user, and they'll be able to just run the script:

```
website = raw_input("Please enter the name of a website to scrape ")
scrape_and_save(website)
```

Users can just double-click on your script and it will pop up a console window, ask for a URL, run and exit. (To keep the console from closing, add `raw_input("press RETURN to exit ")` to the end of your script.) It looks ugly but it works. but yeah, it's not easy to copy text out of the cmd window.

**To present the results in an editor,** you can do it like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["start", "myoutput.txt"])
```

This asks Windows to open `myoutput.txt` using whatever editor it uses when you double-click on a `.txt` file (probably Notepad).

*Addendum:* If your target audience knows about the command line, you can pass the URL as an argument instead. Call your script like this

```
% python myscript.py http://example.com
```

and your script can find the website in the array `sys.argv`.

Comment: If you double-click the script, it opens and runs in Command Prompt and then exits, without allowing the user to do anything with the output. I paused the script at the end of the output, but Command Prompt doesn't play nice with copy/paste. So, to get a less volatile output with copy/paste ability, I run the script from IDLE.

The editor solution may work best, but what happens to the .txt file? Is it a temporary file that goes away after use (which would be perfect)?

My intended audience probably doesn't even know what Command Prompt is.

Comment: You create the txt file, you remove it if you don't want it to stick around (and/or create it in C:\temp). To keep the console from closing, add another `raw_input`!